Combining two Terraform output maps into one (line by line)
First and most important thanks in advance for assistance on this one.
I have two TF output maps below from vpc creation that need to be combined into required result:
azs = 
{ "vpc_name1" = tolist([ "eu-west-2a", "eu-west-2b", "eu-west-2c", ]) 
  "vpc_name2" = tolist([ "eu-west-2a", "eu-west-2b", "eu-west-2c", ]) } 

private_subnets = 
{ "vpc_name1" = [ "subnet-a", "subnet-b", "subnet-c", ] 
  "vpc_name2" = [ "subnet-d", "subnet-e", "subnet-f", ] }

Required result:
If vpc_name1 is selected return subnets1 output below.  If vpc_name2 is selected return subnets2 output.
module "xxx” { 
for_each = var.x 
  subnets = each.value.vpc_name == "vpc_name1" ? // return subnets1
}

vpc_name1 output:
+ subnets1 = { 
    + "eu-west-2a" = { 
        + id = "subnet-a” 
        } 
    + "eu-west-2b" = { 
        + id = "subnet-b” 
        } 
    + "eu-west-2c" = { 
        + id = "subnet-c” 
        } 
    }

vpc_name2 output:
+ subnets2 = { 
    + "eu-west-2a" = { 
        + id = "subnet-d” 
        } 
    + "eu-west-2b" = { 
        + id = "subnet-e” 
        } 
    + "eu-west-2c" = { 
        + id = "subnet-f” 
        } 
    }

I have researched join command but that does not combine line by line.

What do you mean by If vpc_name1 is selected  selected how?

module "xxx” {
for_each = var.x
subnets =  each.value.vpc_name == "vpc_name1" ? // return subnets1 output
}

I'm not quite sure about how the vpc name is selected, so i'm going to assume that is passed as an input in a variable, that way I can build an example:
variable "selected_vpc" {
  default = "vpc_name1"
}

locals {
  azs = {
    "vpc_name1" = ["eu-west-2a", "eu-west-2b", "eu-west-2c"]
    "vpc_name2" = ["eu-west-2a", "eu-west-2b", "eu-west-2c"]
  }
  private_subnets = {
    "vpc_name1" = ["subnet-a", "subnet-b", "subnet-c"]
    "vpc_name2" = ["subnet-d", "subnet-e", "subnet-f"]
  }
}

output "test" {
  value = {
    for i, x in local.azs[var.selected_vpc] :
    (x) => { "id" : local.private_subnets[var.selected_vpc][i] }
  }
}

another assumption my code makes is that the azs and the private_subnets have the same amount of elements, if not that might cause errors

a terraform plan on that will look like:
Changes to Outputs:
  + test = {
      + eu-west-2a = {
          + id = "subnet-a"
        }
      + eu-west-2b = {
          + id = "subnet-b"
        }
      + eu-west-2c = {
          + id = "subnet-c"
        }
    }


Thanks, this is very close to the required output, I've updated the required output blocks in question if you could let me know updates required.

@BP2000 you say very close but the output to me looks exactly what you are asking for

thanks, however still having issues with output as list you provided for test are maps of [{},[},{}] and need output of {} where eu-west-2a {} eu-west-2b...are in single map {}.  Many thanks

@BP2000 I made the change to be a map instead of a list of objects, see the diff in the revisions: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78465198/revisions ... now that assumes the items in the azs are unique, if not i'm afraid you might get errors

Thankyou, all working.
